# How to find conflicting parts of the code while / after executing git pull --rebase?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

After I did my changes to the code in the master branch I got a request (from another colleague) to merge my changes with those that have happened on the remote master branch.

I more details I needed to run `git pull --rebase`. As a result of it I should expect some merge conflicts that I have to merge manually. My colleague told me that my changes and changes on remote master are in conflict.

However, after I have executed `git pull --rebase`, I did not see any indication of a merge conflict. I got the following (cryptic to me) message:

```
Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
Auto-merging dir1/dir2/dir3/my_script.py
```

So, my expectation was that it is the file where the merge conflicts should happen. However, when I open the file, I do not see any stuff that I usually see in case of a merge conflict (things like  `HEAD` or `<<<<<<` and so on).

So, my question is: How to identify conflicting parts of two versions of code (from remote master and local master).

Comment: There is no conflict, git automatically handled the "conflicting" changes in the merge. The end result should be fine, you might want to check it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Your merge issues have been auto-merged in the file mentioned. There is no conflict as such in the file. As per this statement:-

> Falling back to patching base and 3-way merge...
>       Auto-merging dir1/dir2/dir3/my_script.py

The dir1/dir2/dir3/my_script.py file has been auto merged by git 3-way merging strategy. Conflict occurs when the auto merge by git cannot be succefully done and need manual intervention.
 If there is a conflict occured you can see a head with the arrows in the file showing both old and updated statements in the file and choose to solve the conflicts.